# How to change the date format to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SqlServer 2000 and VB6

Table

```
Dates

10/10/2009 (dd/mm/yyyy)
11/10/2009
....
....
```

Dates Column Data type is datetime

I want to change the format to string like this '20091010', '20091011'

Expected Output

```
Dates

20091010 (yyyymmdd)
20091011
....
....
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need Query Help

Comment: Why do this in SQL? Do it in the application, just before display.

Comment: You cant do that in a query, you can do it using your application's language... What do you use? PHP, ASP, JSP etc...?

Comment: @oded, i want to view the table in reports, so i don't want to make a code....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), YOUR_DATE_COLUMN_NAME, 112) from TABLE_NAME
```

Should do the trick

You can substitue 112 for [other format from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)